# React Query - How to find out which mutation led to refetching of query

Tags: react-query

In my simple ToDo app i am using `useQuery()` to fetch ToDo's from the server as well as `useMutation()` to create, update and delete ToDo's. When a mutation is successful, i invalidate the query so it gets refetched.

If i press the delete button of a ToDo item, i want the corresponding button to show a loading spinner until the mutation is done and the new ToDo's have been fetched. For that purpose i am using the `useIsFetching()` hook in my components, which works fine. However, here is the problem:

If i now execute a mutation, every button (meaning the "Delete" button as well as the "Submit" and "Save changes" button to post or update a ToDo) will show the loading spinner instead of just the one that i pressed. This makes sense since they all depend on the same value of `useIsFetching()`. I need a way to figure out which mutation led to the refetching of the query so i can conditionally render the loading spinner for the appropriate button. This seems to be a very common problem for me yet i cannot find a (not overcomplicated) solution for it. Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution Ahmed Sbai said above is good (you can use state instead of local variables), and here is another approach for you.

You can check condition based on `isLoading` in the object returned from `useMutation()`.

**Updated:** As written in this [TkDodo's blog](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query), the "magic" is here:

> If you want your *mutation to stay in `loading` state* while your related queries update, you have to *return the result of `invalidateQueries()` from the callback*.

Therefore, you won't need to use the `useIsFetching()` hook, too.

```
function App() {
  const addMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (newTodo) => {
      return axios.post('/todos', newTodo)
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      return queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['todos'],
      })
    }
  })

  const updateMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (id, data) => {
      return axios.patch(`/todos/${id}`, data)
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      return queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['todos'],
      })
    }
  })

  const deleteMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (id) => {
      return axios.delete(`/todos/${id}`)
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      return queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['todos'],
      })
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <button
        onClick={() => addMutation.mutate(...)}
        loading={addMutation.isLoading}
      >
        Submit
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={() => updateMutation.mutate(...)}
        loading={updateMutation.isLoading}
      >
        Save changes
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={() => deleteMutation.mutate(...)}
        loading={deleteMutation.isLoading}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you want any further information, please read more in [Docs](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/mutations).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this is not working sadly as i want to show the loading spinner not only until mutation is finished but also until refetching of the query is finished. That is why i am using the useIsFetching() hook. But this useIsFetching hook gives me no information about what is causing the refetching.

Comment: I'm sorry for not covering the case loading until the refetching is finished. 
Finally, I found a completely solution from TkDodo's blog (https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query). 

Thanks to this "awaited Promises", you won't need to mess things up with redux anymore, I guess.

Please refer to my updated answer above.

Comment: I tested with my deleteMutation and it worked as expected! ^^ Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a variable `var loadingType = 0` and update its value each time the user click on a button for example if the delete button is clicked then `loadingType = 1` if update button `loadingType = 2`, etc. Then based on the value of `loadingType` you know which loading spinner you have to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is that i have these buttons in different components, which means i would have to use react context api or redux to give all of them access to this variable. I hoped that there would be a simple react query solution for this as it is (in my view) a common problem. But guess i have to do it that way.

Comment: Yes you can share the value with redux